# Correlation between convergence radius of complex series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

What do we know about the convergence between complex power series that look almost the same?
For instance, if we have  series 
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n z^n,$ 
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n z^{n+1},$
and 
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^2 z^n.$ 
Can we found out the radius of the convergence  of the second or third series if we know the radius of the first series? Also I want to understand why.

Comment: Are you looking for a sort of algebra?

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the radius of convergence $R$ of a series $\sum\limits_na_nz^n$ is characterized by the following pair of conditions:

- For every $r\lt R$, $|a_n|r^n\to0$ when $n\to\infty$
- For every $r\gt R$, the sequence $|a_n|r^n$ is unbounded

This should imply directly that the radius of convergence of $\sum\limits_na_nz^{n+k}$ is $R$ and the radius of convergence of $\sum\limits_na_n^kz^n$ is $R^k$, for every nonnegative integer $k$.

If it does not, please describe the problem.